# Passing variable from class to class and store the variable Actionscript 3.0

Tags: oop, function, variables, actionscript, constructor

I want to transfer the variables score from ***GameScreen.as*** to ***GameOverScreen.as***.

The method from ***GameOverScreen.as*** is called **getScore(score:Number)**, that doesn't update the **finalScore** from the constructor of ***GameOverScreen.as***.

Is there the way to ensure that the **finalScore** has the same value as the **scorePoints** from the ***GameScreen.as***? *(P.S I tried finding the answer but there's no avail.)*

Here's the code:

GameScreen.as

```
package  
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.*;

/**
 * ...
 * @author xxxx
 */
public class GameScreen extends MovieClip
{
    private var mainClass:main;
    private var enemy:Enemy;
    private var timer:Timer;
    public var scorePoints:Number;

    public var gameOverScreen:GameOverScreen;

    private var debugValue:Number;

    public function GameScreen(passedClass:main) 
    {
        mainClass = passedClass;

        gameOverScreen = new GameOverScreen();

        enemy = new Enemy();
        addChild(enemy);                        

        debugValue = 1;

        scorePoints = 0;

        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);

        ClickToWinButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickToWin);


    }

    private function clickToWin(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        scorePoints += 50;

    }


    private function onAdd(e:Event):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdd);
        init();
    }

    private function init():void 
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameScreenProgress);
    }

    public function gameScreenProgress(e:Event):void 
    {
        ScoreText.text = "Score: " + scorePoints;

        if (enemy.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true))
        {

            mainClass.showGameOver();

            gameOverScreen.getScore(scorePoints);

            enemy.removeEnemy();

        }
    }


   }

  }
```

GameOverScreen.as

```
package  
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.text.*;
/**
 * ...
 * @author xxxx
 */
public class GameOverScreen extends MovieClip
{
    private var mainClass:main;

    private var gameScreen:GameScreen;

    public var finalScore:Number;

    public function GameOverScreen() 
    {


        ScoreText.text = "" + finalScore;

    }

    public function getScore(score:Number)
    {
        finalScore = score;
        trace(finalScore);
    }


    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your `GameOverScreen` only updates the `ScoreText.text` in the constructor.  The constructor is **only** executed when the `GameOverScreen` is created.

Later, after the `GameOverScreen` has been created, you call the `getScore()` method and pass in the final score. But all the `getScore()` method does is update the `finalScore` variable... **it does not actually update the text field with the actual score**.

What you should probably do is remove this line from the constructor:

```
ScoreText.text = "" + finalScore;
```

And put it in your `getScore()` method.  I would also consider renaming `getScore()` to `setScore()` -- because it is setting the score, not retrieving it...

```
public function setScore(score:Number)
{
    finalScore = score;
    trace(finalScore);
    ScoreText.text = "" + finalScore;
}
```

Comment: It can't update the finalScore and it gives NAN because I placed the ScoreText.text in the GameOverScreen's movieclip. Is there a way for it to change the score? I assume is putting setScore(finalScore) in the constructor but it got error.

Comment: Can you add the code for the main class? I'm not sure I follow what is happening from your comments.

Comment: Is it better if I can send you the code and the fla through email or dropbox?

Comment: @Minelava Don't forget to return finalScore, then in your other AS you could write "GameScreen.finalScore", so 'return finalScore' and 'GameScreen.finalScore'.

Comment: If I write GameScreen.finalScore, I would have TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at GameOverScreen()
 at GameScreen()
 at main/showGame()
 at SplashScreen/debugButtonClick()